# Calling native apps from within Flex(AIR)

Tags: flex4, air

How can i call a native app (could be as simple as executing an .EXE file) from within my Flex (AIR Application)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the NativeProcess class to achieve this. A [tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/interacting_with_native_process.html) is available on the Adobe site.